# Dynamic v-model with nested v-loop

Tags: vue.js

im stuck at building the dynamic form v-model.I need to loop within the data[idx].qty as it shows the number of input. Below is the sample json data :

```
 const data = [ {name: "INDIVIDUAL 7KM",price: "50",qty: 1},{name: "INDIVIDUAL 7KM",price: "50",qty: 3} ]
```

Here is the component:

```
  <div v-bind:key="item[i]" v-for="(item,i) in participantData">
        <el-card
            class="box-card"
            :model="form"
            v-bind:key="koko"
            v-for="(koko,idx) in item.qty"
             style="margin-top:2rem; width :100%">
                  <el-input v-model="form.participants[item.name + koko]"></el-input> </el-card> </div>
```

Comment: `<div v-bind:key="item[i]" v-for="(item,i) in participantData">` is, most likely, wrong. You're indexing the first item by its `0` prop, the second by its `1` prop, and so on... You either use a unique property of the item (i.e: `<div :key="item.id" v-for="item in participantData">`) or just use the index: (i.e: `<div :key="i" v-for="(item, i) in participantData">`)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What you currently posted is not enough for anyone to reproduce your issue and, therefore, to test any potential solution/fix.